# Iterate over property of array with nested array objects

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have an array with nested object arrays given. Each nested array has the property "row":

```
myTextBlock=[
   { "row": [{text: "test1", category: 1}, {text: "test2", category: 2}, {text: "test3", category: 1}]},
   { "row": [{text: "test4", category: 2}, {text: "test5", category: 1}, {text: "test6", category: 3}]},
   { "row": [{text: "test7", category: 1}, {text: "test8", category: 3}, {text: "test9", category: 1}]}
];
```

I need to iterate over the nested text-key (to concatenate the string while preserving the order, adding a linebreak after every row and adding a comma in between).

Desired outcome:

```
test1 test2 test3 \n test4 test5 test6 \n test7 test8 test9
```

For some reason I can't get the iteration part over the property "row" to work. If you could help me with this part I would work the rest out myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a combination of map and join: `myTextBlock.map(o => o.row.map(r => r.text).join(' ')).join(' \n ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) twice to convert both array levels into single value:

```js
let myTextBlock=[
   { "row": [{text: "test1", category: 1}, {text: "test2", category: 2}, {text: "test3", category: 1}]},
   { "row": [{text: "test4", category: 2}, {text: "test5", category: 1}, {text: "test6", category: 3}]},
   { "row": [{text: "test7", category: 1}, {text: "test8", category: 3}, {text: "test9", category: 1}]}
];

let result = myTextBlock.reduce((state, current) => {
    return state + 
           current.row.reduce((st, cur) => st + cur.text + " ", "")   +  
           "\n";
}, "");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use forEach function of javascript which is an array member function

```
myTextBlock.forEach((obj) => {
    // here you can access the row key from the obj
    obj.row.forEach((textObj) => {
         console.log(textObj);
    }
}
```